# Mostrar variable en texto obtenido desde la base de datos

Tags: laravel

Guardo un texto en la base de datos y dentro de este quiero mostrar unas variables que envío a la vista, pero el texto se muestra plano, no muestra las variables.

He intentado de varias formas, una guardando en la base de datos directamente el texto con las llaves:

```
La cantidad de {{$sd}} // esto es el texto de la BD (campo description)
```

Imprimo de la siguiente manera el texto `{{ $plan->description }}`

Yo esperaba que al imprimirse el texto, muestre el valor de la variable por no, solo muestra el texto plano, también intente de la siguiente manerá

```
La cantidad de &#123;&#123;$sd + $hd&#125;&#125; // esto es el texto de la BD (campo description)
```

Imprimo de la siguiente manera el texto `{!! $plan->description !!}`

Pero lo muestra en un texto plano

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15773349/2553194) tienes varias soluciones para tu mismo problema. Cómo verás, y has constatado, las variables en el texto no se sustituyen solas, se requiere de un procesamiento de lo recuperado de base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda